# Nested menu using Material UI (4.9.2) - React Js (16.8.5)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create nested menu using Material UI, **without any third party packages**.

### What I have Done:

- Created a menu and menu items.
- One of the menu item added a button.
- Opens another menu with menu item.

It is fine functionally, messy but functional.

### Code:

```
    <Button 
            aria-controls="fade-menu" 
            aria-haspopup="true" 
            onClick={handleClick} >  
            EU <ArrowDropDown />
    </Button>
 <Menu
        id="fade-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
{Object.keys(SETTING).map((key: string) => {
    <MenuItem
            key={key}
            onClick={onChange(key)}
            selected={isSelected}>
                 <Button // want this button to be hidden, but functional.
                    aria-controls="fade-menu"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    onClick={handleSubClick}
                  >
                   <ArrowDropDown />
                 </Button>
              <Menu
                    id="fade-menu"
                    aria-controls="fade-menu"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    anchorEl={subAnchorEl}
                    keepMounted
                    open={subOpen}
                    getContentAnchorEl={null}
                    anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "bottom", horizontal: 120 }}
                    transformOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "center" }}
                    onClose={handleSubClose}
                    className={subMenu}
             >
     {Object.keys(euCountries).map((keyId: string) => (
                       <MenuItem
                          key={key}
                          onClick={onChange(keyId,true)}
                          selected={path[type] === keyId}>
                             UK 
                       </MenuItem>))}
                </Menu>
                  
    </MenuItem>
    )})}
</Menu>
```

### The Problem:

I need this button with arrow down icon, integrated with the menu Item itself.

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQrVY.jpg)

Other than using third party packages, any work around is accepted. Like CSS changes or another child component etc.

### Edit:

I want the output to look like this.
[Output I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyOS9.png)

Instead I am gettting this.
[Output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7uuA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe material ui buttons have the startIcon and endIcon tag, no?

For instance:

```
<Button endIcon={<ArrowDropDown/>} ></Button>
```

Comment: This wont work for my issue, please look at the edit.